# List of Android devices with their current version APIs

Tags: android-versions

I have been trying to find a list of Android devices with their *current* Android version that their manufacturers upgraded to.  Not the ones that the were released with.  Most of the lists I find are either incomplete or out-of-date.

Does anybody know of such a list?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is the most complete list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices

If you wanna see in % -> http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

Comment: Here is a list of phones that gets an Android 4 upgrade: http://www.freeyourandroid.com/inthenews/ics-devices

Comment: That wikipedia article is one of the ones I found to be outdated.  For example, the Motorola Xoom claims to have 3.0, but I know for a fact it's been updated to 3.2.  It does seem to be the most complete list, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This?

`Marshmallow 6.0           API level 23
Lollipop    5.1           API level 22
Lollipop    5.0           API level 21
KitKat      4.4 - 4.4.4   API level 19
Jelly Bean  4.3.x         API level 18
Jelly Bean  4.2.x         API level 17
Jelly Bean  4.1.x         API level 16
ICS         4.0.3 - 4.0.4 API level 15, NDK 8
ICS         4.0.1 - 4.0.2 API level 14, NDK 7
Honeycomb   3.2.x         API level 13
Honeycomb   3.1           API level 12, NDK 6
Honeycomb   3.0           API level 11
Gingerbread 2.3.3 - 2.3.7 API level 10
Gingerbread 2.3.0 - 2.3.3 API level 9, NDK 5
Froyo       2.2.x         API level 8, NDK 4
Eclair      2.1           API level 7, NDK 3
Eclair      2.0.1         API level 6
Eclair      2.0           API level 5
Donut       1.6           API level 4, NDK 2
Cupcake     1.5           API level 3, NDK 1
(alpha?)    1.1           API level 2
(beta?)     1.0           API level 1`

Source: https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html

Comment: I asked this years ago, but I was looking for a list of the devices and what OS they are currently using. For example, what OS is the Galaxy Note 1 using, what OS is the HTC One m7 using and so on. Not the API levels of the OSs.

Comment: @Deev, http://bluestacks.com/blog/app-reviews/archive/list-of-android-devices.html ?

Comment: That would be what I was looking for but it looks like it hasn't been updated in six years.